# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on

Tags: php

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetable\class.ManageUsers.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\timetable\login.php(19): ManageUsers->LoginUsers('nazrin@gmail.co...', 'abc123') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetable\class.ManageUsers.php on line 22"

i am getting this error and was wondering how to fix it?

```
class ManageUsers{
    public $link;

    function __construct(){
        $db_connection = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    function registerUsers($password, $ip_address, $date, $time, $username, $email, $uname){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (password,ip_address,date,time,username, email, uname) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array ($password, $ip_address, $date, $time, $username, $email, $uname);
        $query->execute($values);
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }

    function LoginUsers($username, $password){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;
    }

    function GetUserInfo($username){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowCount ==1)
        {
            $result = $query->fetchAll();
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return $rowCount;
        }
    }

}
```

?

Comment: which mysql api are you using to connect with? your code suggests PDO, is it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `rowCount()` is strictly a PDO convention. mysqli has nothing similar

Comment: @Machavity well I know that *lol* but how many times I've seen OP's using another instead. I just had to ask.

Comment: @rain The TL;DR answer is that `$db_connection->connect()` failed to return a PDO object. You'll have to debug the connection system to figure out why

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, that's true. I have seen API confusion more times than I care to count.